# Do intra-Schengen flights into Zurich deplane into the departures concourse?

Tags: schengen, airports, zurich, zrh

When arriving at the Zurich airport on a flight from another Schengen country, do you deplane into the departures concourse (i.e. like domestic flights in the U.S.?) I'm aware that there's not supposed to be any passport control, but I'm wondering if you would still be inside the secure airside area or not (and, thus, whether you could access airside services like restaurants or lounges before leaving the terminal.)

Comment: I remember transiting at Zurich airport a couple of years ago and arriving airside, so I guess that means yes.

Comment: I distinctly remember not having to go through security again, even inbound from the UK. Just go through the most half-hearted passport check ever and then you're in the departures area

Comment: With all due respect, the original title better reflects what I'm trying to ask, IMO. I'm not asking about shopping; I just wanted to know if the flights deplane into the departures area or not (as opposed to a separate international arrivals area or outside security.) The comments are helpful. If either of you wants to make that into an answer, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: http://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/arrivals-and-departures/transfers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember transiting at Zurich Airport a couple of years ago (both flights on one Swiss ticket) and arriving airside, so I guess that means yes for you.

[Wikipedia has some more info on the airport infrastructure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrich_Airport#Infrastructure) It's not super-clear but I read

> Arriving Schengen and non-Schengen passengers are handled in separate areas of the Airside Center and reach the Airport Center by different routes, with non-Schengen passengers first passing through immigration controls.

as confirming the above.

Finally [a trip report on Sleeping in Airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/zurich.htm) is in agreement with that.

Answer (score 1):

Last year I had a transit through Zurich on my way to Malaga from Amsterdam. You land and are taken directly to the terminal; where there are plenty of shops and restaurants.

This is all in the secure air-side area.